# awk to reformat output if input file is expty

Tags: awk

The `awk` below works perfect if the `file` used to perform the calculation has data in it. If the `file` is empty or 0KB, then I get incorrect output. I am trying to put a condition in the bwlow that will check for `file` being empty and if `file` is not empty then the output remains the same, but if `file` is empty then the output is reformatted to the desired output of 4 zeros, `tab-delimited`.  My attempt to do this is in the `# check if empty` below. Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk '
  # print from stored values
  function prt(){
    print p1 ":" (p6start==1 ? p2 : p2+p6start) "-" p2+p6, "\t" p5
  }
  ($4!=p4 || $6!=p6+1) {
    # new sequence, print the previous sequence
    if (NR>1) prt()
    p6start=$6  
  }
  {
    # store the values that we need later
    p1=$1
    p2=$2
    p4=$4
    p5=$5
    p6=$6
  }
  END { prt() }
' file | awk -F"[:-]" '
  { print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4}
' > output # make low coverage
# check if empty
if [ -s aFile ]; then  
else  
  output={ print "0     0     0     0" }
fi
```

**desired output** (if file is empty)

```
0     0     0     0      --- 4 zeros seperated by tabs
```

If `file` is not empty it will look like the below and the output will be as expected. However if `file` is empty and doesn't look like the below that is when the output needs to be reformatted. Thank you very much :)

**file**

```
chr2    50573818    50574097    chr2:50573818-50574097  NRXN1   267 2
```

**edit**

using the `file` above as input for the `awk` the output will be:

**output**

```
chr2    50574085    50574085    NRXN1
```

this is expected and works assuming the `file` is formatted accordingly. If `file` is empty and those fields do not exist the `awk` produces output that is different than the expected. So if `file` is empty then can the output be reformatted to four zeros that are separated by tabs?

Comment: Please provide concise, testable sample input and expected output for both empty and non-empty files as your current approach of multiple awk scripts and pipes and testing the file outside of awk is wrong so rather than putting a bandaid on it lets just help you do it the right way.

Comment: I added some details in the edit section that I hope will be enough detail.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: Not really. I mean given the input and output you've shown us so far all you need is something like `awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5} END{if (NR==0) print 0, 0, 0, 0}' file` to produce the output you say you want from the input you've posted (empty or otherwise) but theres nothing in your one-line input file to explain whats changing it in the output and given how much code you've also posted I can't believe it's really that simple so there must be SOMETHING about your problem that you haven't included in your sample input/output yet.

Comment: I think my confusion or lack of understanding is that the `awk` I posted executes on a variety of different data. If the `file` is empty I run in to a problem that adding that line would fix. However, how do I apply it to only an empty `file`.  It really might be a simple thing but I am not that advanced yet though I am getting better thanks to all the great help here and from Robbins "Effective Awk Programming". Thank you very much :).

Comment: I'm trying to tell you what you need to do so we can help you. Your current approach is simply wrong. Trying to add onto that so it'll work with empty files would not make it more right. To be able to help you we need to see concise, testable sample input and expected output. For input you posted 1 line but your script seems to expect multiple lines of input. For the expected output you also posted 1 line but didn't explain the transformation you want applied to the input to produce that output (especially mysterious if it's really 1 line of input alone that produces it). Help us to help you.

Comment: I will post back tomorrow with more details as I do not have access to complete file. I am always finding new conditions in my data. Thank you very much for your help :).

Comment: Consider something like `NF >= 6` as an additional criteria for each of your awk clauses.  This means you need 6+ columns in order to do anything. If you output with printf and `%d` then undefined variables become zeros.  Also, you only need one awk command.